# Using Powershell to Filter All Excel Files in a Folder

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm very new to Powershell but I'm hoping this is something easy and I've just gotten the snippets of code pieced together wrong. I'm getting a run error with the following code which I hoped would loop through all files in a folder and subfolders and put filters on all of the files in there. All of the files will always be .xlsx if that helps.

```
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
Write "Loading Files..."
$path = "C:\test"
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\test\*.xlsx
Write "Files Loaded."
ForEach ($file in $files)
{

## Instantiate the COM object
$excelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excelWorkBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open($path)
$excelWorkSheet = $excelObj.WorkSheets.item("sheet1")
$excelWorkSheet.activate()

## Turn on auto-filter
$headerRange = $excelWorkSheet.Range("a1","z1").AutoFilter() | Out-Null

## close everything
$excelWorkBook.Save()
$excelWorkBook.Close()
$excelObj.Quit()

## make sure the process is really gone...
Get-Process | where {$_.Name -like "Excel*"} | % {
    $Id = $_.id
    if ((Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessID = '$id'" | select CommandLine) -like "*embed*")
    {
        Stop-Process -Id $id -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting..?

Comment: A foreach loop has the format `foreach ($a in $b) {<repeating code block>}`  After your foreach () an opening curly brace ({) is expected, but it is not there

Comment: It's just a generic cmd error from what I read: The external program "powershell" returned an error code: 1

Can you tell me what the code should look like with the curly brace in it please? Not sure where it would go and if there needs to be a close to it as well? I tried putting it before the $excelObj command but got the same error

Comment: in addition to the bad foreach format mentioned by GertJanKraaijeveld, this >>> `$excelObj.Workbooks.Open($excelFileFath)` uses a $var that is not defined anywhere in your sample code. where does `$excelFileFath` get its value? [*grin*]

Comment: Oh! good point. I'm definitely new to this. So I'm thinking instead of $excelfilepath it should be $files right? since that's where the files that are looping are located.

Comment: I have edited the post to included changes I made based on comments so far, however I am still getting the same run error. Any ideas?

Comment: You are still missing a curly brace at the last line of your file, the parent `foreach($file in $files)` loop is not closed. Open your file in the Powershell ISE and it should have a red squiggly under the first brace

Comment: OK the code is fixed with the final curly bracket. Thank you all!